# How to get index of the model when it is removed from collection - backbone

Tags: backbone.js

How can i get the index of the model when it is removed from the collection.
In the below code there is a callback function doSomething(){} which is called when remove is fired and i would want the index there.

Backbone doc says "*The model's index before removal is available to listeners as   options.index",*
 but i get options is undefined.

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});    

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model : MyModel 
});

var data = [

    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 600
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": 800
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "value": 700
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "value": 100
    }

];

var newCollection = new MyCollection();
newCollection.on('remove',doSomething);
newCollection.reset(data);

function doSomething(){/* how to get the index of the deleted model */}
newCollection.remove(newCollection.at(2));

console.log(newCollection);
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Qmg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function doSomething(model, collection, options) {
    console.log(options.index);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/Z7Qmg/1/